# My program doesn't execute because of an static value

Tags: c++, c

I have this chunk of a program that merges two arrays in one. The matter is that I got this message once the program is compiled:

```
main.cpp:20:21: error: storage size of ‘cont’ isn’t known
```

Why does it happen?

Leave my code below:

```
int * merge(int *array_1, int *array_2, int n1, int n2)
{
static int cont[n1 + n2];

int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;

while(i < n1 && j < n2)
    if(array_1[i] < array_2[j])
        cont[ k++ ] = array_1[ i++ ];
    else
        cont[ k++ ] = array_2[ j++ ];
        
if(i == n1)
    for(int index = j; index < n2; index++)
        cont[ k++ ] = array_2[ index ];
else if(j == n2)
    for(int index = i; index < n1; index++)
        cont[ k++ ] = array_1[ index ];

for(int i = 0; i < k; i++)
    printf("%d ", cont[i]);

return cont;
}
```

Comment: The size of array "cont" should be constant expression, because the size of the array must be clear at compile time.
Use int* cont = new int[n1 + n2];

Comment: static int cont[n1 + n2];
n1 and n2 should be const int, not int, compiler need knows value of it until execute programm

Comment: In C++, array dimensions must be fixed at compile time.  Support of VLAs (variable length arrays) in C was introduced in C99, and made optional (i.e. the compiler doesn't have to support them) in C11.      Even `const` int values cannot be used, since they may not be determined at compile time.  C++11 and later, `constexpr` is suitable.    If the dimensions are not known at compile time, then in C (if VLAs are not supported) it is necessary to use dynamic memory allocation or, in C++, use a standard container like `std::vector`.

Comment: Which language are you using, C or C++?  In C++ you can use `std::vector`, which can grow at runtime and is easier to pass to functions.  The C language doesn't have vectors.  Please update your language tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C++ a static array needs to have a size which is known during compile time. If you do not know the size beforehand it is by default a dynamic array independently if it residing on the stack: `int my_array[n]` or on the heap: `int* my_array = new int[n]` (The latter is strictly speaking not an array but behaves similar)

So essentially if you want to dynamically create the array you need to drop the `static`. However given how it is used in your example it will either way not work, because you return the address of a local variable which will be destructed when leaving the scope. Essentially your return value will point into no-mans-lands.

I would suggest to use `std::vector` instead. Please note that I also adjusted the insert logic and made it a bit easier to read because I had trouble to figure out which order your wanted to achieve when going through your example. Now it is ordered the following way:

- values from array1 and and array2 are inserted alternating.
- If one array is longer than the other those values are added in the end.

```cpp
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> merge(int *array_1, int *array_2, int n1, int n2)
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    int shorter_length = n1 < n2 ? n1 : n2;
    for (int i = 0; i < shorter_length; i++) {
        v.push_back(array_1[i]);
        v.push_back(array_2[i]);
    }
    for (int j = shorter_length; j < n1; ++j) {
        v.push_back(array_1[j]);
    }
    for (int j = shorter_length; j < n2; ++j) {
        v.push_back(array_2[j]);
    }

    for(auto& element : v)
        printf("%d ", element);

    return v;
}
```

You can play around with this example: https://godbolt.org/z/fT6xzo

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed, fully explained answer! It happens to be so useful. Greetings!

Answer (score 0):

1. the initialized static variable will be put in the "data" segment, so the compiler should know how much space should be allocated for it in the executable file.
2. the uninitialized static variable will be put the "bss" segment, although there will no exactly size of space left for it in the executable file (*because data in "bss" segment is all zero, so the compiler can just leave a start address and a size is enough. when the executable file be loaded into memory, the loader will allocate real memory for the "bss" segment according to the start address and the size*). the compiler should also know the size of the variable too, only in this way, the compiler can 'tell' this size to loader, so that the loader can know how much memory should be allocated for the "bss" segment when loading the executable into memory.